# How to copy text from (or paste to) Putty

Tags: copy, putty, paste

this is similar to the question found here:
[How do I copy text from PuTTY to another window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654609/how-do-i-copy-text-from-putty-to-another-window#654610)

I have tried all suggestions mentioned in that link, using the mouse to highlight text, but it does not work.

To clarify, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (up to date) and have installed the latest version of Putty (0.70 at the time of writing this question). The previous version had no ability to copy/paste either, at least on my machine.

I can see the text being highlighted as I hold down the left mouse button, but on release, there is nothing copied to clipboard and as such an attempted paste (in Libre Office Writer for example) shows nothing. The middle mouse button appears to act like the Enter key and is therefore no good, and the right hand mouse button acts similarly to the left hand mouse button.

So fundamentally, my question is how do you copy text out of putty, or for that matter, into putty? Being able to copy commands into putty would be a very useful time-saver.

If this is meant to work, then perhaps this should be a bug report...

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple:

Select the text in the Putty window.
Go to Text Editor and click on right button (the scroll button). It will paste.

If you need to paste a command into putty, you can copy in other window and right click (scroll button) on Putty window.

Comment: Thanks Luisdarui. Being a former windows user I'm more used to the conventional means of using the clipboard. To clarify for other users who may experience the same problem, I'll elaborate a little on your answer:
1. Select text (Use right mouse button and drag across text to copy)
2. Go to application or screen where you wish to paste, and click the middle mouse button (or scroll wheel button, either will work). Text is now pasted in position.
Using this method I have found I can copy/paste just about any text anywhere, so it's useful for a lot more than just PuTTy.

Answer (score 1):

Select text and press ctrl + right mouse button and it will show option to copy text to clipboard and we can paste it anywhere we want

Thanks